# RSVP to Facebook events without using Facebook

Tags: windows, facebook

Every time I log into Facebook I end up wasting time checking my notifications and/or browsing the newsfeed. Is there a Windows application or webapp that allows you to view the events you have been invited to on Facebook and RSVP, but doesn't show notifications or the newsfeed?

I know that most calendars will allows you to sync your Facebook events, but I haven't seen any that let you RSVP

Comment: Syncing is easy as it is just done with ical. (All facebook users have a semisecret ICal Feed. (semisecret as in not super highly advertised)).

Comment: @Oxinabox: I know about syncing, but does this let you RSVP?

Comment: No it doesn't. Sorry, my original comment was to say that iCal is not used for setting the RSVP on the events, so a real solution must use the Facebook API.
(I must have accidentally deleted my second sentence)

Answer (score 1):

[Sunrise calendar](https://calendar.sunrise.am/) allows you to do this from the web. Simply click the Sunrise icon in the app to view event invites. There are also apps for mobile devices and Mac.